# Img alt attribute localization failed on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localization, alt-attribute

I want to localize the img alt attribute on an asp.net project so it could be multilingual. I want it preferably to be in LocalResources and not Global. Also i want to know if this can happen without making the img to asp:Image.

```
<img meta:resourcekey="WhoCalls" alt="Who calls?" src=""
     style="opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);"/>
```

I want something like this:

```
<img  alt="<%$ Resources:Default.aspx, HelloResource %>" src=""
     style="opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);"/>
```

Any Ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how exactly have you proceeded with this but this should have worked. Refer following links to corss-check what you have done :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx 
 and 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38907/ASP-NET-Localization-Quick-Reference and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Please check again. I edited the post so you can see how i set it. I've already seen the posts. Thank you for your comment